# How to have a 2-dimensional array as a private variable in a class, and then set it in the constructor

Tags: c++, arrays

In my platformer game which I'm writing in Visual C++, each level will initially be stored as a 2-dimensional array of ints. I decided it would make more sense to store this array in a class, so I created a class called Level. It looks like this:

```
class Level {
private:
    int map[20][30];
public:
    Level(int a[20][30]) {
        map = a;
    }
    int getcell(int row, int column) {
        return map[row][column];
    }
};
```

As far as I can see - from looking up tutorials on class constructors, and passing 2-dimensional arrays as parameters, this should work, so I really don't understand why it doesn't.
On the line where I do `map = a`, I get an error: `Error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue`. I've looked this error up on stackoverflow, but I can't find any answers which relate to my problem.
So, how can I fix this error?

Comment: Since arrays are not lvalues, that error is pretty explicit in its description. An array-type variable cannot, by itself, appear as the left side of an assignment. Code a loop (or fire up some standard lib functions like `std::memcpy`, which would work in this case).

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't really have anything to do with a constructor. You cannot assign arrays in C++. Whether in the constructor, or anywhere else.

There are two ways to work around it. The first way is the brute force way. Instead of

```
map = a;
```

write a loop to copy the contents of the array from the constructor's parameter into the class member array.

The second way is to stuff the array into an intermediate class:

```
class Level {

public:
    struct level_map {
        int map[20][30];
    };
private:
    level_map map;
public:
    Level(const level_map &initial_map) : map(initial_map)
    {
    }
    int getcell(int row, int column) {
        return level_map.map[row][column];
    }
};
```

This may or may not be practical, and introduces a little bit more complexity.

But the real answer here is to use `std::vector`s instead of plain arrays, which will solve all of these problems.

Comment: Thanks! This mostly works, although on your `getcell` function, it tries to return the level_map instead of an int, which is the return type of the function.

Comment: also, how would I use the `std::vector` to do this?

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> map`

Answer (score 2):

Others have already mentioned the real reason: you cannot assign an array to another using `=` operator. My two cents about your class:

- `map` is not a good name, it may get conflict with `std::map` if `using namespace std;` or `using std::map` was specified somewhere.
- The constant array sizes make this class non-reusable. Class should be flexible to allow any N*M sized 2D array. For this, better to use `vector<vector<int>>`.
- `getcell` should be a `const` method, and it should do error checking with row and column numbers passed.

If you want this class to have static-sized array sizes and compile time, you may use class templates with row and column sizes as non type template arguments.

```
template<size_t row, size_t column>
class Level
{
    int _map[row][column];
public:
    Level(int src[row][column])
    {
        memcpy(_map, src, sizeof(_map));    // why not simply 'memcpy' ?
    }
};

int main()
{
    int source[10][2] = { {1, 2}, {3,4} };
    Level<10, 2> ten_by_2(source);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the `map` is a constant value, which could not been assigned as an lvalue. This could be fixed by iterating the element of the array, and assign `a[i][j]` to `map[i][j]`.

```
class Level {
private:
    int map[20][30];
public:
    Level(int a[20][30]) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
            for(int j = 0; j < 30; ++j)
                map[i][j] = a[i][j];

    }
    int getcell(int row, int column) {
        return map[row][column];
    }
};
```